# Toggle vue2-editor view content to html

Tags: vuejs2, quill

I am using `vue2-editor` and i want to toggle the content view of the editor like `ckeditor` or `mailchimp` editor does

[image]
[image]

It is possible using `vue2-editor` or `quill`?

Answer (score -1):

You can have a computed property that either returns the actual text or uses a library like [hypertext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hypertext) to generate html, the return value of the html would be contingent on another computed property and returns the html you want.

I also have a simpler solution, which I used once but need to take a look at my code in a few hours which is not in front of me.